# Manipulate AWK field variables ($1,$2,..) and add that to the end of line

Tags: linux, awk, sed, cut

I am trying to create /etc/host file from ansible inventory file.

Ansible inventory file looks like this:

```
[masters]
k8s-master-a.example.com ansible_ssh_host=10.15.90.2
k8s-master-b.example.com ansible_ssh_host=10.15.90.3
k8s-master-c.example.com ansible_ssh_host=10.15.90.4
[etcd]
k8s-etcd-a.example.com ansible_ssh_host=10.15.91.2
k8s-etcd-b.example.com ansible_ssh_host=10.15.91.3
k8s-etcd-c.example.com ansible_ssh_host=10.15.91.4
```

The following script will help to create it with fqdn entry.

```
$cat inventory.yaml | grep -v '^\[' | sed 's/ansible_ssh_host=//g' | awk '{ print $2 " " $1}' > /etc/hosts
```

```
10.15.90.2 k8s-master-a.example.com  
10.15.90.3 k8s-master-b.example.com  
10.15.90.4 k8s-master-c.example.com  
10.15.91.2 k8s-etcd-a.example.com 
10.15.91.3 k8s-etcd-b.example.com 
10.15.91.4 k8s-etcd-c.example.com
```

But I want to have k8s-master-* and k8s-etcd-*  aslo in the /etc/hosts file. The final result should look like this.

```
10.15.90.2 k8s-master-a.example.com k8s-master-a
10.15.90.3 k8s-master-b.example.com k8s-master-b
10.15.90.4 k8s-master-c.example.com k8s-master-c
10.15.91.2 k8s-etcd-a.example.com k8s-etcd-a
10.15.91.3 k8s-etcd-b.example.com k8s-etcd-b
10.15.91.4 k8s-etcd-c.example.com k8s-etcd-c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWK solution:

```
awk -F'[ =]' '/^[^\[]/ { if (match($1,/\./)) print($NF " " $1 " " substr($1,0,RSTART-1)); }'
```

Test:

```
$ awk -F'[ =]' '/^[^\[]/ { if (match($1,/\./)) print($NF " " $1 " " substr($1,0,RSTART-1)); }' inventory.yaml
10.15.90.2 k8s-master-a.example.com k8s-master-a
10.15.90.3 k8s-master-b.example.com k8s-master-b
10.15.90.4 k8s-master-c.example.com k8s-master-c
10.15.91.2 k8s-etcd-a.example.com k8s-etcd-a
10.15.91.3 k8s-etcd-b.example.com k8s-etcd-b
10.15.91.4 k8s-etcd-c.example.com k8s-etcd-c
```

Comment: strings, fields, and array indices in awk start at 1, not 0, so 0 is an invalid value for the 2nd argument to substr(). You only get the output you want from it because awk treats all invalid values in that context as if they were `1`. Try it with `substr($0,-127,RSTART-1)` and you'll get the same result. So, change `substr($0,0` to `substr($0,1` so the code is using valid values.Use `print $NF, $1, ...` instead of hard-coding the `" "` value of `OFS`. You don't need to escape `[` inside a bracket expression `/^[^[]/` is fine.

Comment: Also since you want to treat `.` literally you should just be using `s=index($1,".")` which expects a literal string instead of using match() which expects a regexp and then escaping `.` so it's treated literally. Obviously you'd then use `s-1` instead of `RSTART-1` in the `substr()` call.

Answer (score 2):

You just need `awk` for that. This will do the job:

```
cat inventory.yaml 
[masters]
k8s-master-a.example.com ansible_ssh_host=10.15.90.2
k8s-master-b.example.com ansible_ssh_host=10.15.90.3
k8s-master-c.example.com ansible_ssh_host=10.15.90.4
[etcd]
k8s-etcd-a.example.com ansible_ssh_host=10.15.91.2
k8s-etcd-b.example.com ansible_ssh_host=10.15.91.3
k8s-etcd-c.example.com ansible_ssh_host=10.15.91.4

awk -F'[[:space:]=]' '/^[^[]/ {split($1, tokens, /[.]/); print $3, $1, tokens[1]}' inventory.yaml  
10.15.90.2 k8s-master-a.example.com k8s-master-a
10.15.90.3 k8s-master-b.example.com k8s-master-b
10.15.90.4 k8s-master-c.example.com k8s-master-c
10.15.91.2 k8s-etcd-a.example.com k8s-etcd-a
10.15.91.3 k8s-etcd-b.example.com k8s-etcd-b
10.15.91.4 k8s-etcd-c.example.com k8s-etcd-c
```

Comment: Sure! It is almost the same. :-)

Answer (score 0):

if data in 'd' file, tried on gnu awk:

```
awk -F'[.= ]' '$0!~/^\[/{print $5"."$6"."$7"."$8,$1,$2"."$3,$1}' d
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F'[=[:space:]]+' 'split($1,f,/[.]/)>1{print $NF, $1, f[1]}' file
10.15.90.2 k8s-master-a.example.com k8s-master-a
10.15.90.3 k8s-master-b.example.com k8s-master-b
10.15.90.4 k8s-master-c.example.com k8s-master-c
10.15.91.2 k8s-etcd-a.example.com k8s-etcd-a
10.15.91.3 k8s-etcd-b.example.com k8s-etcd-b
10.15.91.4 k8s-etcd-c.example.com k8s-etcd-c
```